# How to Make Dynamic Validation List Reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a drop-down list in a range of cells, as given in the loop below. The list I want to pull is from `B5` on `Summary!` (`wsSumm`) to the last populated column in that row.

The code below keeps throwing "Application defined or object defined error" on line of code where I define the list range `"=Summary!$B$5:" & wsSumm.Cells(5, LastCol)`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Dim i As Integer

Dim LastCol As Integer

LastCol = wsSumm.Range("B5").End(xlToRight).Column

For i = (NumScenariosRow + 4) To (NumScenariosRow + NumScenarios - 1)
With CtrlPanel.Range("B" & i).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=Summary!$B$5:" & wsSumm.Cells(5, LastCol)
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to add a `.Address` to the end of the cell reference.